# Detect a change when values typed in placeholder

Tags: button, pyqt, pyqt4, placeholder, form-layout

I have a form layout where I'm typing some value using `QLineEdit(self).setPlaceholderText("Write your name")`. I'm writing the value and I'm pressing 'OK' button and after that I need to print this value to screen. How should I do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to your lineedit, so that you can ask it what content is has later on.

To be put in your code:

```
self.q = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
self.q.setPlaceholderText("Write your name")
# user does their thing
print( self.q.text() )
```

The last line of course goes wherever you deal with the OK button having been pressed.